# Re-posting an answer in a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I put up this answer yesterday: [Is it a foregone conclusion that religion will always be a product of developing a civilisation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23463/is-it-a-foregone-conclusion-that-religion-will-always-be-a-product-of-developing/23468#23468)

However, the question was then marked duplicate.  Would it be kosher to re-post that answer in the original, still open question? [Can civilization development occur completely without faith?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/371/can-civilization-development-occur-completely-without-faith)

I'm just sad to see it go since I put a fair amount of time into the research/lookup.  Maybe delete the answer in the duplicate to avoid rep fishing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the answer answers the other question, it's completely kosher to move it there.  (Move, not copy, as you said.)

Sometimes duplicate questions are not *exact* duplicates, so do review your answer against the other question and make sure it answers that question.  If the question was closed as a dupe then you *should* need only minor changes (if any) to bring that about.

Comment: Flag for Moderator Intervention, then edit after the move?

Comment: You should be able to do it all yourself, unless your answer was accepted.  Copy to the open question, edit as needed, delete from the closed question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure I've seen a 3rd question along these lines as well. In fact I've a funny feeling I might have asked it. Not got time to check now though.